# crear un servidor capaz de atender multiples clientes en python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

por el momento mi servidor puede atender solo un cliente con el cual puedo enviar mensajes de texto, me gustaria poder conectarme con otro cliente y hacer lo mismo

```
#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

datos = sock.recv(4096)
print (datos.decode('utf-8'))



while True:


  message = input("envia un mensaje")
  sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))




  if message == "quit":
    break
    print("bye")
    sock.close()




#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        try:

             print('conexion con {}.'.format(addr))

             conn.send("server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))

             while True:

                 datos = conn.recv(4096)
                 if datos:
                     print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('utf-8')))

                 else:
                     print("prueba")
                     break



        finally:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: te recomiendo leer sobre websockets de python , eso es lo que estas haciendo,

Comment: @JackNavaRow El código del usuario es un socket TCP típico. No tiene nada qué ver con websockets, que son otra cosa completamente diferente.

Comment: @steven Básicamente tienes tres formas de logar que atienda a varios clientes: crear múltiples procesos para cada cliente (usar `fork()`, no funcionaría en Windows), crear múltiples hilos, uno para cada cliente (usar `threading`), bien creando uno nuevo cada vez que llega un cliente o bien teniendo un _pool_ de hilos previamente creados que se van repartiendo el trabajo; finalmente, usando un solo proceso y un solo hilo mediante un bucle de eventos asíncrono basado en el módulo `select`, o en la nueva `asyncio`. Esto último es bastante complejo, pero altamente escalable.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con el siguiente servidor, puedes mejorarlo y hacerlo a tu gusto, el único cambio que hay es el módulo threading.

```
#servidor
import socket
import threading

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")


def worker(*args):
    conn = args[0]
    addr = args[1]
    try:
        print('conexion con {}.'.format(addr))
        conn.send("server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(4096)
            if datos:
                print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('utf-8')))

            else:
                print("prueba")
                break
    finally:
        conn.close()

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```

Saludos